# Do all geth calls require hex data?

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc

Taking `eth_getLogs` as an example. Here's the original POST data:

```
{
    "id": 67,
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "eth_getLogs",
    "params": [{
        "fromBlock": 3138480,
        "toBlock": 3138482,
        "topics": ["0x000000000000000000000000a94f5374fce5edbc8e2a8697c15331677e6ebf0b"]
    }]
}
```

If I do that I get:

```
"error": {
    "code": -32602,
    "message": "invalid argument 0: hex string without 0x prefix"
}
```

With:

```
"params": [{
    "fromBlock": "0x2fe3b0",
    "toBlock": "0x2fe3b2",
    "topics": ["0x000000000000000000000000a94f5374fce5edbc8e2a8697c15331677e6ebf0b"]
}]
```

It works okay. `0x2fe3b0` is the hex representation of `3138480`, while `0x2fe3b2` is for `3138482`.

The question is if this is the case for all geth calls?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, from the [wiki page](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#hex-value-encoding)

> At present there are two key datatypes that are passed over JSON: unformatted byte arrays and quantities. Both are passed with a hex encoding.